# How to save this Kalanchoe red lips?

Tags: succulents

I've had this plant for about 9 months now. At first it was doing fine, with a few baby plants growing on the sides of the main stem. Then the leaves started drying out and falling, bottom to top, firstly on the main stem, later even on the smaller ones. There are also brown spots on the leaves - I don't think they are pests. Is there anything that can be done? Thanks! 
[image]

Comment: The plant appears to be wet, including the topgrowth - why is that? Also the soil looks pretty wet, so its likely a fungal infection, possibly from overhead watering and too much watering, but how often do you water, how much and in what manner that you manage to get the foliage wet?

Comment: Well, at some point I do have to water it, right? I had just done so when I took this picture. I had also sprayed some antitranspirant on it, since the leaves are drying out. I don't water it that often, once a week.

Comment: ah right,that  explains why the stem and foliage look wet  - what product do you mean when you say 'antitranspirant'?